# Rolify not have a particular role check condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rolify

I am using rolify for assign various roles to a user. Like admin, professor, student, staff.

I am to define a condition where I have to specify that this particular condition is true for only those users who are not admin.

I know how to check if a user is admin

```
u=User.first
u.has_role?(:admin)
```

But I not able to figure out how to check the user doesn't have the role of admin?

Please help me get a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement this method in user model, this means that the user has other roles but not admin

```
def has_not_role?(role)
  roles.where.not(name: role).exists?
end
```

Comment: Why not simply `!has_role?(role)` this way the functionality stays completely uniform?